# How often to derive from boost::signals::trackable?

Tags: c++, boost, coding-style, boost-signals, boost-signals2

When using Boost.Signals, boost allows you to derive from `boost::signals::trackable` in order to ease object/connection lifetime management (See the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/signals/s06.html#id3150100)).

I am in an early stage of my project and I am thinking, whether to derive from `boost::signals::trackable` in

- every new class I write that might use Boost.Signals in the future
- or only in classes I am sure that they will need the functionality of the `trackable` bas e-class

The main reason for th first approach would be to prevent me to forget deriving from `boost::signals::trackable`.

Also double deriverations like

```
class Foo : public Base, public boost::signals::trackable
{
};
```

get unnecessary.

On the other side, preventing memory-leaks shouldn't be a main design-aspect. Testing and profiling tools like valgrind should be used to detect memory leaks.

Which approach is more suitable for growing projects?

Comment: If you are worried, maybe write a set of functions that you always use to connect signals/slots instead of directly using signal::connect that has a static assertion in it that the class must be derived from boost::signals::trackable.   Maybe boost signals offers a way of doing this anyway.  That way, if you forget, your project won't compile.

Comment: Why don't you use `Boost.Signals2`, which has much more flexible and powerful tracking mechanism?

Comment: @IgorR. I haven't taken a look at Boost.Signals2 because I though the multithreading support would slow down my application.

But after having taken a look at the [connection Management](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#id3151565) I am going to use `Boost.Signals2`.

Thanks!

Comment: @Random Citizen you can even disable locking by changing MutexType ty dummy_mutex: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#signals2.tutorial.signal-mutex-template-parameter

Comment: @IgorR. Thanks for your help. Maybe it would be a good idea to post your answer as an official answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `Boost.Signals2` supersedes `Boost.Signals`. It has much more flexible and powerful [tracking mechanism](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/signals2/rationale.html#idp163103664).

Although the library aims to provide a thread-safe solution for multi-threaded programs, the locking overhead can be avoided in a [single-threaded environment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#signals2.tutorial.signal-mutex-template-parameter) by setting `boost::signals2::dummy_mutex` as signal's internal mutex.

Answer (score 1):

## Qt as an alternative

The Qt-Event system enforces programmer to derive from `QObject` so you really are on the save side when using Qt-Events.