# Boost.Signals deprecated

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals, boost-signals2

> Boost.Signals is no longer being actively maintained, so it has been deprecated. Do not use Boost.Signals for new development (use Boost.Signals2 instead). If you have existing Boost.Signals-based code, it will continue to work, but consider moving to Boost.Signals2.

http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_54_0.html

So, Signals are deprecated. I'm confused about this. As far as I know, Signals2 is multi-threaded version of Signals. But what if I don't need multi-threading usage of Signals? Will I get some overhead? Can I use boost::signals2::trackable? Will I get any disadvantages using Signals2 in single-thread application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I know, Signals2 is multi-threaded version of Signals. But
>   what if I don't need multi-threading usage of Signals? Will I get some
>   overhead?

In a single-threaded environment use `dummy_mutex`, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16891540/759253).

> Can I use boost::signals2::trackable?

Yes, you can use it, but keep in mind that it won't be [thread-safe approach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/signals2/trackable.html). So if you eventually decide to adjust your module to a mutli-threaded environment, you'll have to re-design your slots.

Answer (score 0):

Using multithread safe code in a single threaded app is always ok.  You might gain some overhead due to being either overly careful or through useless locking, but it will always work.  And I wouldn't worry about the performance hit-  its very unlikely to be a bottleneck.